# MVC Core 2.0 "Post" action returns null view model

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am working with ASP .Net core 2.0 MVC website. In this, I have one controlller, one view model and a view.

View Model is of type

```
 class ViewModelClassName
{
    public int property1;
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> property2;
}
```

I come to know through previous thread that if properties are not displayed in the editable fields, they will return null. In view I displayed all the properties either in hidden or visible form in the fields. Still form submission returns null. Is Dictionary as shown in code a valid way to store? If not, what can be the alternatives?

Comment: The default model binder works with *properties*, not *fields*. Use `public int property1 { get; set; }` and `public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> property2 { get; set; }`. However, we need to see the View code to check if that's the only problem

Comment: Don't post partial code. Please provide the complete code to understand the scenario properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use properties instead of field.
It should be like

```
class ViewModelClassName
{
    public int Property1 { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, string>> Property2 { get; set; }
}
```

Reason behind using properites is because default model binder works with properpties.

**Update:**
If you need to understand how dictionary binding work, refer to below link
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Comment: Still returning view model null

Comment: Sorry, code is proprietary cannot post directly. I can explain the problem. In the view, Property2 being dictionary, when I try @HiddenFor(x => x.Property2) or @HiddenFor(x => x.Property2.Keys), it do not bind the model. What could be the solution? Suggestion for some kind of nested for operation for this?